# CHECKBOXLIST no me aparecen sus metodos

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un CheckBoxList pero no me aparecen sus metodos de checked, probe con directivas y referencia pero no me aparecen los metodos del CHECKBOXLIST

```
  protected void btnSeleccionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < chkCuentas.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            chkCuentas.SetItemChecked(i, true);
        }

    }
```

Por ejemplo ese metodo (SetItemChecked) tendria que aparecer pero no me lo reconoce

ALGUNA IDEA?

DESDE YA SE AGRADECE

Comment: pero no te lista ningun metodo o ese concretamente que mencionas no aparece ? Intentaste cerrando el VS, volviendo abrir el desarrollo y realizando un Rebuild de la solucion

Comment: No no me aparece ningun metodo! si probe en cerrarlo , abririlo y ReBuild.

Comment: si defines algun otro control en el form, como ser un textbox y despues intentas acceder a los metodos, los lista? para ver si es cosa de ese control o es general con todos

Comment: no habia visto que es un desarrollo web, ese checkbox es de asp.net o es un html? porque si es html recuerda que debes definirle runat=server para poder accederlos desde codigo servidor

Comment: es un html! osea lo coloco del cuadro de herramientas.. con los otros puedo acceder a sus metodos normalmente! o sera que me falta alguna referencia o directiva?

Comment: ehh si es un html entonces no arrastras de ningun cuadro de herramientas, eso solo aplica a los controles asp.net si en el html visualizas un <asp:CheckBox> eso es un control asp.net

Comment: Si tenes razon ahora que lo veo  de esa manera si es  de ASP

Comment: si cierras todas las solapas del VS y vuelves abrir esta que contiene el checkbox tampoco reconoce los metodos, prueba de agregar otros controles a ver si sucede lo mismo o de ver de acceder desde otros eventos por ejemplo el page load